# My fwrite to a socket is not flushed, until the socket closes. How to change?

Tags: php, networking, sockets

My fwrite to a socket is not flushed, until the socket closes. How to change? I want it to flush after each fwrite.

I've tried:

1) flush() 
2) fflush() 
3) ob_implicit_flush(true);

None of those worked, I still had to quit php for my socket to receive the data.

---

Including some sample code, anything looks wrong?

```
while($clientSocket = socket_accept($this->serviceConnection))
    {                              
        while( $clientMessage = socket_read($clientSocket, 1024)     )                     
        {                  
            echo 'Relaying message to server: ' . $clientMessage;
            if( !fwrite($this->Connection, $clientMessage) )
                echo 'Error writing to server'; 
            fflush($this->Connection);
        }
        socket_close($clientSocket);
    }
```

Comment: maybe not the writing/sending end is the problem but the receiving end?

Comment: The receiving end gets the output when the php script finishes. So it works fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a function for that! [fflush($rc)](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.fflush.php)

Did you make sure you had the correct resource as the parameter?

**edit**

Okay. looking at your code you are using socket_* functions. You need to use fsockopen, fwrite, fflush, fsockclose. Your code should work the same, but you will be able to flush output. check out the example [in the php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fsockopen.php) for more details.

Comment: yea, does it work with network resource created by fsockopen? The doc says only file handles.

Comment: The php manpage for fflush says,

"The file pointer must be valid, and must point to a file successfully opened by fopen() or fsockopen() (and not yet closed by fclose())."