# How use only one socket to send many requests HTTP in PHP?

Tags: php, sockets

I have a PHP Class to push message with socket like :

```
function __construct()
{
     $this->socket = fsockopen($this->host, $this->port, $errno, $errstr, 0); //I tried with 99999 for timeout too
}

function push($params)
{
     $req = 'GET /push?'.$params." HTTP/1.1\r\n"
            . 'Host: '.$this->host."\r\n"
            . "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n"
            . 'Content-Length: '.strlen($params)."\r\n"
            . "Connection: keep-alive\r\n\r\n";

     fwrite($this->socket, $req);
}
```

But if I tried to push 2 or more message, only one is receive by NodeJS serveur :

```
foreach(['foo=2', 'bar=42'] as $loop)
{
   $pusher->push($loop);
}
```

Now, if i put this line `$this->socket = fsockopen($this->host, $this->port, $errno, $errstr, 0);` just before `fwrite`, all messages will be send...

So why I can't use only one connexion for multiple request with same soket?

I use "keep-alive" and I don't call `fclose`, so I don't understand why my nodeJS server receive only one message in first case...

Comment: Are you certain that your server supports pipelined HTTP messages. Even if it does, this can't be done in PHP, because properly implementing pipelined HTTP requests requires asyncronous I/O, in order to correctly handle protocol-level buffering issues, i.e. the socket's output buffer may be full, and cannot accept any more data, and so is the input buffer, because the server is waiting for you to fully read the previous requests's response, and drain the socket. Congratulations: you just deadlocked with the server!

Comment: I don't need the response, jsut Fire and Forget request (and the nodeJS server don't send it), but just to test : how can I empty socket's buffer? thx.

Comment: Have you tried fflush? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2917584/my-fwrite-to-a-socket-is-not-flushed-until-the-socket-closes-how-to-change

Comment: `fflush($this->socket);` change nothing...

Comment: In my local Apache it works without needing to open socket every time. Could it be a matter of your PHP.ini config?

Comment: Possible, What do you think is needed to put in php.ini for this work?

Comment: Even if you do not need the response, you still have to read it, otherwise you're going to deadlock the server, with pipelined HTTP requests.

Comment: Ok, to read response, it's fread() or other function? Can you show me?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I tried fread() to empty buffer, but nothing change... Other idea?